# VB.NET Listbox item can't be edited after I've edited it once

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

I was asked by a friend to make a simple listbox application. Inside the listbox there is one item. It's called 'itemTransfer = "true" '. Once I double-click it, a new form comes up that I added. This form (also called itemTransfer, the same as the listbox item) has a textbox and a button.

Once I type in text into the new textbox and click apply (the new button), it sets the original listbox's item's name to whatever I typed into the second (new) textbox. However, I had trouble with editing the listbox's item after already editing it once.

Here's code from both the original listbox and the other form.

Listbox Code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "itemTransfer = """"" Then
        itemTransfer.Show()
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "itemTransfer = """ + itemTransfer.ComboBox1.Text + """" Then
        itemTransfer.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Code to set the listbox item's name from the combobox:

```
cschangerexe.ListBox1.Items(cschangerexe.ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = "itemTransfer = """ + ComboBox1.Text + """"
```

Note that the program is called "cschangerexe".

However, after a user commented, I looked into the link they provided and after looking way deeper than I did before asking (I didn't think of it at the time) I figured out a solution (or at least workaround for now), here it is (it only affects the original listbox, not the other form).

New Listbox Code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        itemTransfer.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code as code, not as image.

Comment: @Raw N Edited it.

Comment: What are *itemName* and *itemTransfer* ? Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Raw N I completely remade the question, so now it's hopefully more understandable, and since I managed to fix it thanks to your link, I put "Solved" in the title. I provided code for both listbox, the other form and the button.

Comment: Please post an answer and mark it as solved.